# Text auto resize along with some widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, qtextedit, qlabel

I have 3 questions as below:

(1) In tab1, I want my text labels in the first row to auto-match the checkbox/radio buttons below it. When I enlarge the windows, however, it starts to be off the grid.

(2) For the yes/no text in the scroll area: when I enlarge the window, the labels itself become too big than other widgets(i.e. checkbox) inside the scroll area. Not sure what caused this happening?

(3) Those radio buttons codes are a little bit lengthy. I'm thinking to have a for loop to make it simpler, but not sure how to do that by now.

If you know how to solve this issue, pls let me know. Appreciated!

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QGridLayout())

        yesLabel = QLabel('Yes')
        self.layout().addWidget(yesLabel, 0, 3)

        noLabel = QLabel('No')
        self.layout().addWidget(noLabel,0, 4)



        checkBox1 = QCheckBox('1', self)
        checkBox2 = QCheckBox('2', self)
        checkBox3 = QCheckBox('3', self)
        checkBox4 = QCheckBox('4', self)
        checkBox5 = QCheckBox('5', self)
        checkBox6 = QCheckBox('6', self)
        checkBox7 = QCheckBox('7', self)
        checkBox8 = QCheckBox('8', self)
        checkBox9 = QCheckBox('9')
        checkBox10 = QCheckBox('10', self)
        checkBox11 = QCheckBox('11', self)
        checkBox12 = QCheckBox('12', self)
        checkBox13 = QCheckBox('13', self)
        checkBox14 = QCheckBox('14', self)
        checkBox15 = QCheckBox('15', self)
        checkBox16 = QCheckBox ('16', self)

        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox1, 1, 1, 1, 15)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox2, 2, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox3, 3, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox4, 4, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox5, 5, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox6, 6, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox7, 7, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox8, 8, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox9, 9, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox10, 10, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox11, 11, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox12, 12, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox13, 13, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox14, 14, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox15, 15, 1)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBox16, 16, 1)


        radioButton1a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton1b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton1a, 1, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton1b, 1, 4)
        qgroup1 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup1.addButton(radioButton1a)
        qgroup1.addButton(radioButton1b)

        radioButton2a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton2b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton2a, 2, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton2b, 2, 4)
        qgroup2 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup2.addButton(radioButton2a)
        qgroup2.addButton(radioButton2b)

        radioButton3a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton3b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton3a, 3, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton3b, 3, 4)
        qgroup3 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup3.addButton(radioButton3a)
        qgroup3.addButton(radioButton3b)

        radioButton4a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton4b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton4a, 4, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton4b, 4, 4)
        qgroup4 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup4.addButton(radioButton4a)
        qgroup4.addButton(radioButton4b)

        radioButton5a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton5b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton5a, 5, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton5b, 5, 4)
        qgroup5= QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup5.addButton(radioButton5a)
        qgroup5.addButton(radioButton5b)

        radioButton6a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton6b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton6a, 6, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton6b, 6, 4)
        qgroup6 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup6.addButton(radioButton6a)
        qgroup6.addButton(radioButton6b)

        radioButton7a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton7b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton7a, 7, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton7b, 7, 4)
        qgroup7 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup7.addButton(radioButton7a)
        qgroup7.addButton(radioButton7b)

        radioButton8a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton8b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton8a, 8, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton8b, 8, 4)
        qgroup8 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup8.addButton(radioButton8a)
        qgroup8.addButton(radioButton8b)

        radioButton9a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton9b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton9a, 9, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton9b, 9, 4)
        qgroup9 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup9.addButton(radioButton9a)
        qgroup9.addButton(radioButton9b)

        radioButton10a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton10b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton10a, 10, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton10b, 10, 4)
        qgroup10 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup10.addButton(radioButton10a)
        qgroup10.addButton(radioButton10b)

        radioButton11a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton11b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton11a, 11, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton11b, 11, 4)
        qgroup11 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup11.addButton(radioButton11a)
        qgroup11.addButton(radioButton11b)

        radioButton12a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton12b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton12a, 12, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton12b, 12, 4)
        qgroup12 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup12.addButton(radioButton12a)
        qgroup12.addButton(radioButton12b)

        radioButton13a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton13b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton13a, 13, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton13b, 13, 4)
        qgroup13 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup13.addButton(radioButton13a)
        qgroup13.addButton(radioButton13b)

        radioButton14a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton14b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton14a, 14, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton14b, 14, 4)
        qgroup14 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup14.addButton(radioButton14a)
        qgroup14.addButton(radioButton14b)

        radioButton15a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton15b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton15a, 15, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton15b, 15, 4)
        qgroup15 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup15.addButton(radioButton15a)
        qgroup15.addButton(radioButton15b)

        radioButton16a = QRadioButton(self)
        radioButton16b = QRadioButton(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton16a, 16, 3)
        self.layout().addWidget(radioButton16b, 16, 4)
        qgroup16 = QButtonGroup(self)
        qgroup16.addButton(radioButton16a)
        qgroup16.addButton(radioButton16b)

class Tab1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QGridLayout())

        benchmarkLabel = QLabel('someText1')
        self.layout().addWidget(benchmarkLabel, 0,1)
        tatLabel = QLabel('someText2')
        self.layout().addWidget(tatLabel, 0, 3)

        self.group = Widget(self)
        scroll = QScrollArea(self)
        scroll.setWidget(self.group)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.layout().addWidget(scroll, 1, 1, 1, 50)

        checkBoxT1a = QCheckBox('abc', self)
        self.layout().addWidget(checkBoxT1a, 2, 1)

        leT1a = QLineEdit()
        self.layout().addWidget(leT1a, 2, 2)

        runBtn = QPushButton("Run", self)
        self.layout().addWidget(runBtn, 4, 1)


class Page1(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tab1 = Tab1()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QWidget()
        self.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab1")
        self.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab2")
        self.addTab(self.tab3, "Tab3")
        self.tab2_initUI()
        self.tab3_initUI()

    def tab2_initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.tab2.setLayout(grid)

    def tab3_initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.tab3.setLayout(grid)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 600, 370)
        self.startPage1()

    def startPage1(self):
        x = Page1(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("1")
        self.setCentralWidget(x)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: for each question you could put a picture of what you get and you want to get it please.

Comment: @eyllanesc Sure pls see the ballpark pic in the bottom

Comment: Pls run my codes and enlarge the window, you'll soon notice the issues on "someText" and "Yes/No" text thanks:)

Comment: you could explain the third point correctly.

Comment: The third point is that I've a bunch of radio buttons groups. I just want to make the codes for that part simpler (less lines). I guess it can be done with for-loops and .format but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Is there always 2 radiobuttons per row?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes it is. One is in the same column as 'Yes' text, and the other one is with 'No'.

Comment: and how does the number of rows depend?

Comment: The number of rows should be as it is now, which is 17 rows (1 row for text at the top, and 16 rows for checkbox) in total at that scroll area.

Comment: I think what you are doing is a questionnaire where there are a certain amount of questions, and for each question there is an option to select, am I correct?

Comment: Umm not really. It is actually designed to run some other programs. The checkbox each represents one program.

Comment: could you put someText1 and someText2 inside the QScrollArea?

Comment: And yes, it could be inside the QScrollArea. But if doing so, I prefer it is fixed at top row as always even when I scroll the scrollbar.

Comment: To achieve this I will have to use other widget, is there any problem in it?

Comment: No it won't be a problem thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155561/discussion-between-ryan9025-and-eyllanesc).